# Finding all folder and sub-folder content and display like a structure (Java)

Tags: java

I am working on a project that requires me to fetch all the files name and folders (sub-folder) name.
I am trying to do it by using ArrayList named yo in my first approach.

The code from beginning as follow:

```
public ArrayList varToList(File folder) {

        for(File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()){
            if(fileEntry.isDirectory()){
                yo.add(fileEntry.getName());
                varToList(fileEntry);
            } else
                yo.add(fileEntry.getName());
        }
        return yo;
    }
```

The output After the code executed from beginning:

```
[AddFilesDeflateComp.zip, AddFilesDeflateComp1.zip, AddFolder.zip, HAHAFolder, 200HAHA.txt, YO.txt, HAHAFolder.zip, RootText1.txt, RootText2.txt, RootText3.txt, test.zip, TestFolderA, TestFolderA1, text1.txt, Text2.txt, Text3.txt, TextA.txt, TextB.txt, TestFolderB, TestFolderC, TestFolder 4, boss.txt, New folder, play you.txt]
```

Then I switched to another approach as the above is clearly cannot do it.

Here is the code to get the **file structure**:

```
String folderName = "root";
ArrayList<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> previousFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, ArrayList> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList>();
Map<String, ArrayList> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList>();

public void listFilesForFolder(File folder) {
    ArrayList<String> no = new ArrayList<String>();
    files = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            previousFiles = files;
            map2.put(folderName, previousFiles);
            folders.add(folderName);
            folderName = fileEntry.getName();
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            if (folders.size() - 1 != -1) {
                folderName = folders.get(folders.size() - 1);
                folders.remove(folders.get(folders.size() - 1));
                files = map2.get(folderName);

            }
        } else {
            files.add(fileEntry.getName());
            map.put(folderName, files);
        }
    }

}
```

The final content of map as follow:

```
{root=[AddFilesDeflateComp.zip, AddFilesDeflateComp1.zip, AddFolder.zip, HAHAFolder.zip, RootText1.txt, RootText2.txt, RootText3.txt, test.zip], HAHAFolder=[200HAHA.txt, YO.txt], TestFolderA1=[text1.txt, Text2.txt, Text3.txt], TestFolderA=[TextA.txt, TextB.txt], TestFolder 4=[boss.txt, play you.txt]}
```

My expected output:

```
{root=[AddFilesDeflateComp.zip, AddFilesDeflateComp1.zip, AddFolder.zip, HAHAFolder.zip, RootText1.txt, RootText2.txt, RootText3.txt, test.zip],HAHAFolder=[200HAHA.txt, YO.txt],TestFolderA=[TextA.txt,TextB.txt,TestFolderA1=[text1.txt,Text2.txt,Text3.txt],TestFolderB=[TestFolderC=[TestFolder 4=[New folder,boss.txt,play you.txt]]]]}
```

The above code can fetch content of a sub-folder and can get the folder's name but NOT an empty sub-folder or folder

My file structure at the time of the above code is executed:

```
Root/
HAHAFolder
    /200HAHA.txt
    /Yo.txt
TestFolderA
    /TestFolderA1
        /text1.txt
        /Text2.txt
        /Text3.txt
    /TextA.txt
    /TextB.txt
TestFolderB
    /TestFolderC
        /TestFolder 4
            /New folder
            /boss.txt
            /play you.txt
AddFilesDeflateComp.zip
AddFilesDeflateComp1.zip
AddFolder.zip
HAHAFolder.zip
RootText1.txt
RootText2.txt
RootText3.txt
test.zip
```

is there any other approach or how to modify the above code to get what i need

Answer (score 0):

A recursive apporach fits the recursive structure of the file system best, IMHO.

Your first method is not that bad, you only need a List argument to add the items you found:

```
public List<File> addToList(File item, List<File> list) {
     list.add(item);
     if (item.isDirectory()) {
        for(File fileEntry : item.listFiles())
            list = addToList(fileEntry, list);
     }
     return list;
}
```

You call this like:

```
  File topdir = ....;  
  List<File> all = addToList(topdir, new ArrayList<File>());
```

If you just want to print the directory structure:

```
public void printTree(File item, int depth) {
     for (i=0; i< depth; i++) System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.println (item);
     if (item.isDirectory()) {
        for(File fileEntry : item.listFiles())
            printTree(fileEntry, depth+2);
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this method just to get the file name? Your method output will provide the full path of the File, but I wanted to get a file name and folder name only. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @user2982297 Nothing could be easier. See the only line where something is actually added to the list? Replace `item` with `item.get...()` and change the type of the List accordingly, and there you go.

Comment: I tried your method i can get all files name and folders name now.However, the output is a bit confusing. The method cannot categorize the files corresponding folder.That what i am trying to achieve so that i have to write the second code mentioned above.

Comment: `categorize the files corresponding folder` - I am not sure what exactly that means. But maybe that is why I proposed to create a `List<Files>` - you can then go through the list and create a `Map<String, List<String>>` by storing each Files name under the key of its parent pathname.

Comment: I think he is trying to find all the folder , sub-folder , files with a recursion method. Then display it like the expected output he mentioned which is exactly same as the file structure he provided

Comment: @Benny that's what my intention is

Comment: @Benny If he just wants to display it, there is no need to store all that stuff in Lists and Maps. He can just print as he goes, but of course the method should have a `int depth` parameter to control the indendation.

Comment: @Ingo I tried his code and yours. The problem of his code is, He cannot get the sub-folder name without content. I think that's why he is trying to use HashMap in his code. Maybe he should clarify the question.

Comment: @user2982297 Added code to print the tree. You should now have seen enough to implement small changes yourself.

Comment: I am try to get an output like my expected output and make it to JSON String, I need display it in JSP file.

Comment: @user2982297 just adapt the printTree method, then.